# Does SurveyJS support taking a picture directly within the Survey?

Tags: surveyjs

SurveJS has the option to use a FilePicker, but on mobile device this means the File Explorer is opened. We want our users to be able to have immediately using their camera and have the taken picture uploaded as the 'file'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version we are going to release today (v1.9.97) will add [allowCameraAccess](https://github.com/surveyjs/survey-library/pull/6518/files#diff-eb754129cca3a6aea55ba76ff5b62fa62531aaaa967e0df68074b484c2a11a16R43) property into file question.
You will be able to read more about v1.9.97 weekly release [here](https://surveyjs.io/stay-updated/release-notes).

Thank you,
Andrew